# SQL Query to limit rows within a group

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Is it possible to write SQL query to get the first 5 rows for every date in the below table. I am trying to create a sample set for each data which will limit the data i am trying to process.

```
Date    Data
1-Jan   abc
1-Jan   bsd
1-Jan   ejk
1-Jan   srrf
1-Jan   sfj
1-Jan   fj
1-Jan   rgt
2-Jan   jfnv
2-Jan   sdjnv
2-Jan   zdsj
2-Jan   abc
2-Jan   bsd
2-Jan   ejk
2-Jan   srrf
2-Jan   sfj
3-Jan   fj
3-Jan   jdsfh
3-Jan   jfnv
3-Jan   sdjnv
3-Jan   zdsj
3-Jan   abc
3-Jan   bsd
3-Jan   ejk
3-Jan   srrf
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The actual query complexity will depend on that.

Comment: Given OP's other questions my guess is he's using mysql.

Comment: I am actually trying to do in Hive, I think it should follow most of SQL

Comment: For future reference, this is a standard [tag:greatest-n-per-group] question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard SQL approach is to use `row_number()` for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by date order by date) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5;
```

One important caveat:  SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no concept of the "first five rows for each date", unless you have another column that specifies the ordering within each date.  The above takes five arbitrary rows for each date.

Also, not all databases support `row_number()`, even though it is an ANSI standard function.  They usually have some other method for accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: Given that OP is using this to sample the data, arbitrary rows might actually not be an issue for once :D